# Separar un Unsigned Int en bits

Tags: c++

Tengo un Unsigned Int el cual quiero obtener los bits para separar en signo, exponente y parte fraccionaria, siendo signo el primer bit, exponente los 8 siguientes y la parte frac los ultimos 23.

```
Numero::Numero(unsigned int A, unsigned int B){
    a.s=A>>1;
    a.exp=A>>9 & 0x00ff;
    a.frac=A>>23 & 0x00ff;
}
```

siendo A el Unsigned Int y a una struct de la siguiente forma:

```
struct field{
        unsigned int s:1;
        unsigned int exp:8;
        unsigned int frac:23;
    };

    struct field a;
```

Quiero completar los campos s, exp y frac.

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje? ¿[tag:java], [tag:c++] o [tag:c]?

Comment: el lenguaje es c++ pero con tener la idea puedo pasarlo de un lenguaje a otro

Comment: No. No puedes pasar de un lenguaje a otro porque son lenguajes diferentes. Por ejemplo: en [tag:java] no existen los bitfields y tú los estás usando en tu propia pregunta (etiquetada como [tag:java]).

Comment: entonces en c++

Comment: No me termina de quedar claro cual es el problema que tienes. ¿A qué te refieres con eso de que "_quieres completar los campos_"?

Comment: yo tengo un unsigned int que ocupa 32 bit, pues quiero obtener el primer bit y guardarlo en s, los 8 siguientes y guardarlos en exp, y los ultimos 23 guardarlos en frac

Answer (score 2):

> Tengo un Unsigned Int el cual quiero obtener los bits para separar en signo, exponente y parte fraccionaria, siendo signo el primer bit, exponente los 8 siguientes y la parte frac los ultimos 23.

Bien, pues puedes usar máscaras:

```
constexpr unsigned int signo     = 0b10000000'00000000'00000000'00000000;
constexpr unsigned int exponente = 0b01111111'10000000'00000000'00000000;
constexpr unsigned int fraccion  = 0b00000000'01111111'11111111'11111111;
```

Así pues, obtienes los bits en crudo de esta manera:

```
// Signo 1, exponente 2, fracción 2.
unsigned int valor = 0b10000010'00000000'00000000'00000010;
auto s = valor & signo;     // valor decimal de s: 2147483648
auto e = valor & exponente; // valor decimal de e: 33554432
auto f = valor & fraccion;  // valor decimal de f: 2
```

Si quieres los bits desplazados, evidentemente deberás desplazarlos:

```
unsigned int valor = 0b10000010'00000000'00000000'00000010;
auto s = (valor & signo) >> 31;     // valor decimal de s: 1
auto e = (valor & exponente) >> 24; // valor decimal de e: 2
auto f = valor & fraccion;          // valor decimal de f: 2
```

Por lo tanto, puedes construir un `field` así:

```
unsigned int valor = 0b10000010'00000000'00000000'00000010;
field f{(valor & signo) >> 31, (valor & exponente) >> 24, valor & fraccion};
```

Pero, yo evitaría a toda costa usar un campo de bits ya que pueden tener problemas de eficiencia, en su lugar yo crearía un objeto:

```
struct field {
    using tipo = unsigned int;
    static constexpr tipo mascara_signo     = 0b10000000'00000000'00000000'00000000;
    static constexpr tipo mascara_exponente = 0b01111111'10000000'00000000'00000000;
    static constexpr tipo mascara_fraccion  = 0b00000000'01111111'11111111'11111111;

    field() = default;
    field(tipo valor) : valor{valor} {}
    field(tipo signo, tipo exponente, tipo parte_fraccionaria) :
        valor{signo << 31 | exponente << 24 | parte_fraccionaria}
    {}

    tipo signo() const { return (valor & mascara_signo) >> 31; }
    tipo exponente() const { return (valor & mascara_exponente) >> 24; }
    tipo parte_fraccionaria() const { return valor & mascara_fraccion; }
private:
    tipo valor{};
};
```

Puedes ver el código funcinando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zzjo1jyNSOg8MqW6).